# Android - FileOutputStream - app running from eclipse to a tablet

Tags: java, android, save, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

Is it possible to write an object to a file when I have my tablet connected to pc and running my app from eclipse?

```
public static final void save(Store conf) throws Exception {
    File path = new File("test");
    path.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
    ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    try {
        outStream.writeObject(conf);
    }
    finally {
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```

This is my code. `Store` class implements `Serializable` but gives me this error

> 06-17 19:20:05.242: E/AndroidRuntime(17493):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.store/com.example.store.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.store.MainActivity

I have this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
</uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I can run the app and use it normally, but it doesn't write to file.

Thanks

Comment: This error means the system can't find your Activity.

Comment: Make sure your activity is in manifest, with proper package name.

Comment: The MainActivity is in the manifest, I can run the app. The problem is that doesn't save in file.